# Odoo 10 get model name from record

Tags: odoo

I'm creating a log entry within a server action in Odoo 10. This is the server action Python code:

```
if record:
    env['ir.logging'].create({
        'type': 'server',
        'name': 'test',
        'level': record._name,
        'path': 'test',
        'line': 'test,
        'func': '#',
        'message': '#'
    })
```

The line value for `level` of `record._name` gets me the name of the current model as a string, for example, `product.product`, or `sale.order`.

However, I don't think the `_name` attribute is not meant to be part of the public API. Does anyone know of a public way to retrieve the name of the model?

The `model` variable is also available in the server action, which returns `product.product()`. However, want `product.product`, without the parenthesis. I realize I could just use a string method to trim off the `()`, but I'm wondering if there is an intended way to get just the name of the model as a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see another way. `_name` is "private" and you could use `__str__`, which will give you the model name and the ids of the current `RecordSet`. The regex for odoo's model names is `r'^[a-z0-9_.]+$'`, so i suggest, what you've already known: trim off everything at the end.

Comment: Great answer. Although why not get the value of the `_name` attribute directly like `model._name`? Nothing stops you from reading the variable (since it is not actually private, more like a convention) and the documentation of the class clearly dictates that this is the model name.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas the fact that it is not quite "pythonic" does stop me :(